# Cocos2d Xcode - SLComposeViewController Black Screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I've got a Cocos2d game that I've been working on, and I've managed to get it to present an `SLComposeViewController` by creating a button on screen like this:

The header file looks like this:

```
@interface HighScores : Main
@end

@interface socialViewControllerAtTheBottomOfThisClass : UIViewController
@end
```

The code inside the .m file:

```
@implementation HighScores
- (init) {
UIButton *shareButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(screenWidth/2, screenHeight/2, 100, 30)];
[shareButton addTarget:self action:@selector(shareAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (void)shareAction {

// I created a ViewController class at the end of the .m file containing the social stuff
// but I did this and managed to get it to present the SLComposeViewController:

socialViewControllerAtTheBottomOfThisClass *bottomController = [[socialViewControllerAtTheBottomOfThisClass alloc] init];
[[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] window] setRootViewController:bottomController];
[bottomController shareToFacebook];

}
}
@end
```

Then at the bottom for the ViewController implementation:

```
@implementation socialViewControllerAtTheBottomOfThisClass

- (void)shareToFacebook {
if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {

SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
[controller setInitialText:@"This is my facebook status!"];

[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];

controller.completionHandler = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
switch(result) {
case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled: [self actionForCancelled];
break;
case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone: [self actionForDone];
break;
}};

}
}

- (void)actionForCancelled {
}
- (void)actionForDone {
}

@end
```

The code presents the SLComposeViewController, but while presenting, I get a black background and after I tap either Post or Cancel, the screen stays black. I was thinking of setting the rootViewController as HighScores, but seeing as it's not a ViewController, I'm not able to do that.

Comment: I've managed to get a white screen to show up by running [[CCDirector shareDirector] replaceWithScene:[Game scene]];

Comment: Dont change the root view controller. Try just presenting it like any other view controller on [[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView].

Comment: Tried this dude, my version of Cocos2d is old - so to do this I have to do: [[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] window] rootViewController] presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];

But for some reason, it won't present it? Any ideas haha?

Comment: I don't have the code where I am at now, but I believe in the past I created the SLComposeViewController and added it as a subview similar to:

[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubView:controller.view]; And to remove it you'll have to remove the subview. You can also try:

AppController* app = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[[app navController] presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

Comment: Glad to help. I'll move my response to an answer so you can accept it.

Comment: I added the answer below for you to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the code where I am at now, but I believe in the past I created the SLComposeViewController and added it as a subview similar to:

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubView:controller.view];
```

And to remove it you'll have to remove the subview. You can also try:

```
AppController* app = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[[app navController] presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```